# protobuf timestamp: Use Java 8 time.Instant

Tags: java, protocol-buffers

I'm using protobuf, and one of my message uses the `google.protobuf.Timestamp` type.

When generating the Java-Code, the resulting protobuf classes use `com.google.protobuf.Timestamp`.

Is there a way to tell protobuf to use the new Java 8 types (e.g. `time.Instant`) instead? I don't want the type conversion clutter my code, everywhere I use protobuf. Ideally, it is done inside the generated code itself.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

```
Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochSecond(timestamp.getSeconds(), timestamp.getNanos());
```

Comment: In cases where a short piece of code is self-explanatory and is helpful to users searching for the problem, omitting text to focus on important parts should be OK. Here, the number of upvotes speaks for itself.

Answer (score 13):

### `java.time.Instant` to `com.google.protobuf.Timestamp` :

```
com.google.protobuf.Timestamp.newBuilder()
    .setSeconds(myInstant.getEpochSecond())
    .setNanos(myInstant.getNano());
```

### `com.google.protobuf.Timestamp` to `java.time.Instant` :

```
Instant.ofEpochSecond(myProtoTimestamp.getSeconds(), myProtoTimestamp.getNanos());
```

Comment: In the question, i asked to change the types used in generated Code specifically to avoid this piece of code.

Answer (score 8):

If anyone's writing in Kotlin, [Louis' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55188201/2219288) can be implemented as an extension function like this:

```
fun Timestamp.toInstant(): Instant = Instant.ofEpochSecond(seconds, nanos.toLong())
```

Then you can just do `myProto.myTimestampField.toInstant()`

Answer (score 2):

Not sure about an option for making the generation generate it as you want it, but may be a better approach would be to check at the gRPC documentation here:

https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/java/com/google/protobuf/util/Timestamps

And pick the best one that suits for you.
For example:

```
Instant anInstant = Instant.ofEpochMilli(com.google.protobuf.util.Timestamps.toMillis(someGoogleProtobufTimestamp));
```

Would look a lot shorter and nice once you import properly (just showing the packages used in the example)